# Refine Raster Layer / remove Color bleeding

Tags: raster, vectorization

I have a Raster layer of Population density in a low resolution.

[image]

These raster layer has color bleeding between the different population areas. Is there a way, to remove them in QGIS like color quantisation of the most dominant values to have indexed colors without the bleeding?

And is there a way in QGIS, to "simplify" the areas to get a result like in that picture, maybe something like vectorization and simplify:

[image]